# How to reset my war village to be the same as my normal village?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I've had a village layout that I used for my "normal" village and a different layout for the "war" village. Now I upgraded my TH and rearranged my "normal" village to a new layout that I want to use for my war village as well.

Is there a way to "reset" the war village and tell it to have the same layout as the normal one instead of manually rearranging it each time I change something?

Comment: **#1a Forum exclusive Sneak Peek** You asked for it, we obliged! You can now copy your current village layout to your Clan War base with one button, yay!!! From http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/309871-Sneak-Peeks-D-D-D-D-D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>Currently there is no way to copy your village to your war base. You must modify your war base by hand.</strike>

This is a thread about this [here](http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/275845-Edit-clan-war-base-problem), on the Clash Of Clans forums.

### Update:

As of Version 6.186.1 (released 3rd July 2014) you can copy your current village layout to your Clan War base.

To do this you must be participating in a Clan War on preparation day. Firstly tap on the clan war button and then tap "Edit War Base". Finally tap "Copy Layout" and then "Okay":

[image]

Your current village layout will be copied to your War Base!

[Source](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Version_History#Version_6.186.1_-_3rd_July_2014_.22Hero_Changes.22)